# APACHE2: avoid https:// REDIRECT to open phpmyadmin

Tags: redirect, phpmyadmin, apache2

I have a site https://example.net 
to ensure that all users go to the https:// I set up a redirect with APACHE (on the default.conf) as followed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.net
        Redirect permanent / https://emalsys.net
        # DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net/
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

My issue is when I try to access my phpmyadmin `example.net/phpmyadmin` I redirect to `https://example.net/phpmyadmin` and the page cannot be displayed.
(It is obviously working if I remove the Redirect).
How can I get avoid the redirect only for my phpmyadmin?
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use in my servers to force HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

For other examples see Apache's wiki https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a REWRITECOND before a rewriterule:

```
REWRITECOND %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin
REWRITERULE / https://emalsys.net
```

Answer (score 0):

A way around: 
I do not know why but if I type as url `example.net/phpmyadmin` I will be redirected to `https://example.netphpmyadmin/` but if I write `https://example.net/phpmyadmin/` (with the **/**)I go to php my admin.
No idea why but I hope it will be of help to others.

to force https:// on pyp myadmin I added: `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` at the end of phpMyAdmin’s config.inc.php file (see http://thebarton.org/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/).